# How to pass UserId in NUnit?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, nunit

I'm scratching my head a bit trying to figure out how to test something like the following : 
**Here is GetProjects method.**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/UserProject/GetUserProjects")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetProjects()
{
    string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    try
    {
        List<ProjectDto> userProjectsDtos = projectBll.GetProjects(userId);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, userProjectsDtos);
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
     }
}
```

**And Here I am trying to Run NUnit test for that method.**

```
[TestClass]
public class TestUserProjects
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetUserProjectsTest()
    {
        // Arragnge
        var controller = new UserProjectController();
        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

        foreach (var testUserId in GetTestUserIds())
        {
            // Act
            var response = controller.GetProjects();

            // Assert
            List<ProjectDto> projects;
            Assert.IsTrue(response.TryGetContentValue<List<ProjectDto>>(out projects));
            //Assert.AreEqual(5, projects.Count); // Check projects count
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK,response.StatusCode);
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode,"GetUserProjects : id is {0} and count is {1}",testUserId,projects.Count);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetUserProjects : for id {0} ProjectCount = {1}", testUserId, projects.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass **userId** , but don't know where to write that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the request is suppose to be authenticated then the `User` property should be populated with the principle of the authenticated user. During a unit test however this is not populated by the framework.

For `ApiController` you can set `User` property during arranging the unit test. That `GetUserId()` extension method however is looking for a `ClaimsIdentity` so you should provide one

```
[TestClass]
public class TestUserProjects {
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetUserProjectsTest() {
        // Arrange
        var controller = new UserProjectController();
        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

        foreach (var testUserId in GetTestUserIds()) {
            //Arrange specific user
            var identity = new GenericIdentity(testUserId, "");
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, testUserId.ToString()));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, testUserId.ToString()));

            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles: new string[] { });
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(principal);

            controller.User = user;

            // Act
            var response = controller.GetProjects();

            // Assert
            List<ProjectDto> projects;
            Assert.IsTrue(response.TryGetContentValue<List<ProjectDto>>(out projects));
            //Assert.AreEqual(5, projects.Count); // Check projects count
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK,response.StatusCode);
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode,"GetUserProjects : id is {0} and count is {1}",testUserId,projects.Count);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetUserProjects : for id {0} ProjectCount = {1}", testUserId, projects.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue. Now I don't need to change code that is already written.

Answer (score 1):

Its not "mockable", you should create a different function which will receive a username as a parameter.

Your WebAPI will call the function, and your test will test the logic.

Comment: For that, will I have to change existing code of apicontroller ? Or there is another way around ?

Comment: You will need to change the existing code of apicontroller, extracting the logic out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Static access creates hard dependencies that can't easily be ignored during testing.

The solution is to pull that dependency out of the method under test. I would do something like so the `IUserProvider` dependency can be mocked when testing and provide whatever user id is appropriate for the test.

```
public interface IUserProvider
{
    public string GetUserId();
}

public class UserProvider : IUserProvider
{
    public string GetUserId()
    {
        return User.Identity.GetUserId();
    }
}

public class UserProjectController
{
    private IUserProvider UserProvider { get; set;}

    public UserProjectController(IUserProvider userProvider)
    {
        UserProvider = userProvider;
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/UserProject/GetUserProjects")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetProjects()
    {
        string userId = UserProvider.GetUserId();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        try
        {
            List<ProjectDto> userProjectsDtos = projectBll.GetProjects(userId);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, userProjectsDtos);
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
         }
    }
}
```

The syntax to mock IUserProvider when testing will change with different test frameworks.  Using [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) it looks like this

```
[TestClass]
public class TestUserProjects
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetUserProjectsTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var userProviderMock = new Mock<IUserProvider>();
        userProviderMock.Setup(userProvider => userProvider.GetUserId())
                        .Returns("4e934c03-b02f-47bf-8bdf-e1c98a737cc6");
        var controller = new UserProjectController(userProviderMock.Object);
        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

        foreach (var testUserId in GetTestUserIds())
        {
            // Act
            var response = controller.GetProjects();

            // Assert
            List<ProjectDto> projects;
            Assert.IsTrue(response.TryGetContentValue<List<ProjectDto>>(out projects));
            //Assert.AreEqual(5, projects.Count); // Check projects count
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK,response.StatusCode);
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode,"GetUserProjects : id is {0} and count is {1}",testUserId,projects.Count);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetUserProjects : for id {0} ProjectCount = {1}", testUserId, projects.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

The first lines in the arrange section new create a mock of `IUserProvider` and setup `GetUserId()` to return a test user id.

Comment: This is nice way. One thing is still unclear. How would I call getUserId method and using that userId get UserProjects in NUnit ? Because I want to test GetProjects() for different users.